# Reference for representations of $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z})$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, modular-representation-theory

I was looking for a reference on representations of $GL_n(\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z})$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$. In particular what the irreducible and indecomposable representations look like.

Comment: Over $\mathbb{C}$, this problem is open for $n \geq 3$ and $k$ arbitrary.

Comment: For irreducible representations, it reduces to the case k=1 (where a lot of things are known thank to the theory of polynomial representations, for example, even if the dimensions of the irreducible representations is generally unknown) because the kernel of the canonical surjective group morphism onto $GL_n(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ is a $p$-group.

Comment: Ahh didn't know the problem was still open. Thanks for the replies.